# Google Analytcis Track Hash Links in one page website

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to track hash links with google analytics. And I just tried to configure google tag manager with this configuration.
[image]

[image]

But still I can't track my [website](http://buul.co).

Comment: Check this out: https://www.simoahava.com/gtm-tips/track-url-fragments-as-pageviews/

Comment: If you use the debug mode, what do you see as the page view is tracked? (check out all your events within the GTM debug toolbar)
You can inspect the variables value ("page path with hashtag").